# Conditional check for "i == (2^8)" fails when i is 512?

Tags: c

Here is a small Program to print powers of 2 till 8. But it is not quitting after 8. Please explain the reason.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void)
{
        unsigned int i=1;
        while(1) {
                i = i<<1;
                printf("i = %d\n",i);
                if(i==(2^8))
                        break;
                sleep(1);
        }
        printf("Exited While loop.. \n");
        return 0;
}
```

The Loop is not Exiting when i = 2^8. My output is something like this:

```
i = 2
i = 4
i = 8
i = 16
i = 32
i = 64
i = 128
i = 256
i = 512 (Should have Exited here. But the program is continuing. Why?)
i = 1024
i = 2048
i = 4096....
```

**EDIT :**

Thanks for answering that ^ is an XOR operator. But now the below code is behaving strange. Please Explain.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
        if((2)^8 == 1<<8) {
                printf("True.. \n");
        } else {
                printf("False..!!");
        }
        return 0;
}
```

The above function program prints true.

Comment: Since everybody seems to have failed to mention it, I'll just note it here: *in languages that support it*, the standard exponentiation operator is the double asterisk, e.g. 2**8, 7**3, etc...

Comment: @Thomas Thanks. But in C it is showing a Syntax error.

Comment: C isn't one of those languages. It's just a bonus in case you come across a language that does (Python, some Pascal dialects, perhaps Java?)

Comment: In some dialects of Basic, ^ was the exponentiation operator. I don't recall seeing it in any other languages, though.

Comment: +1 for a well-asked question that included all relevant source code and examples of errant execution. But in general, the edit is right on the line where it might have been better to ask a new question about the mystery since it really isn't a clarification of *this* question.

Comment: @RBerteig Thanks. I myself edited the Question. Before posting the question, i wrote a small program (Edit section) and checked if both are same or not. It was returning true there and in the original program it was returning false. Now things are clear. Thanks SO

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In C, the ^ operator means XOR (bitwise exclusive or).

To get 2 to the power of 8, you need to either use a loop (res *=2 in a loop), or round the pow function in math.h (note that the math.h function returns float - and therefore won't be equal to the integer).

The simplest method is the bitwise shift, of course.

**About the edit section:**

Welcome to the wonderful world of [operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Operator_precedence). 
What happens is that == has higher precedence than ^, and therefore the conditional evaluates to 2^0, which is 2, which is true.

To make it work, you need to add parentheses:

```
if ( (2^8) == (1<<8) ) ...
```

Comment: Please look at my Edit section in the question.

Comment: Thanks. Its clear now. But why did it evaluate to 2^0. even if it is 2^0 which is 2, how is it returning 1 when being compared to 1?

Comment: No no, 8 == (1<<8) evaluated to 0, which was then xored with 2, which was evaluated to 2. If (x) goes to the "true" clause if x is not 0, so you get "True...".

Comment: "note that the math.h function returns float - and therefore won't be equal to the integer" No, `pow(3)` returns a double, and will therefore be exactly accurate for the entire range of a 32 bit integer (and most of a 64 bit one too).

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that `^` is the [Bitwise XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR) operator, not raise to power. Let's explain `2^8` in bitwise format:

```
2 = 0010
8 = 1000
======== xor
10= 1010
```

so the result, applying xor bit by bit, is 10, that never happens so your loop never exits.
You can make your unit test working if you use `pow(2,8)` and round to integer instead.

Another information, it is probably not the case in this example, but it is better  to avoid  the strict equality when working with floating point values, compare with an epsilon is better.

**For your edit:**
Ensure the precedence with this:

```
if((2^8) == (1<<8))
```

this will return false, as expected.

Answer (score 6):

`2^8` is `2 XOR 8`, ie. 10, not 256. hence your loop doesn't stop. You probably want to check against either `(1<<8)` or 256 specifically.

Answer (score 3):

`^` is not power in c, it means `XOR`. 2^8==10 and it will not equal to i in this code.

Answer (score 1):

^ is bitwise XOR, the function you are looking for is pow in math.h :)

Answer (score 1):

**For your edit Section**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        if((2^8) == (1<<8)) {
                printf("True.. \n");
        } else {
                printf("False..!!");
        }
        return 0;
}
```

It will return **False**.

Comment: You might want  to explain **why** it returns false.